# Bad URI with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, uri

I am making an Oauth call to the Facebook API to get myself an access_token

```
def access_token
  token_uri = URI("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=#{CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=#{CLIENT_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials")
  token_response = HTTParty.get(token_uri)
  Rails.logger.info(token_response)
  return token_response
end
```

I get a response and a access_token generated, let's say it's

```
access_token=123456789|abcdefghijk
```

but when I then try to use this token

```
def get_feed
  fb_access_token = access_token
 uri = URI("https://graph.facebook.com/#{VANDALS_ID}/posts/?#{fb_access_token}")
```

end

I get an error

```
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?)
```

and the uri generated stops at the | even though there are more characters after the pipe to complete my access_key

```
https://graph.facebook.com/id-here/posts/?access_token=123456789|
```

How do I get the full access token available in my URI?

Comment: Do you really assume `access_token=123456789|abcdefghijk`? That is very strange. Do you have a method or a local variable named `abcdefghijk`?

Comment: its an example, dont want to be putting REAL access tokens on here do i, the tokens I am getting back have special characters in them, thats my point

Comment: @sawa the format is correct, FB uses `app_id|app_secret`

Comment: try `uri = URI(URI.escape "https://graph.facebook.com/#{VANDALS_ID}/posts/?#{fb_access_token}")`

Comment: @Stefan Is that bitwise *or*?

Comment: @BroiSatse thank you, thats worked, what is URI.escape doing here? would you like to put that down as an answer ?

Comment: @sawa no, just a pipe character / vertical bar

Comment: @Richlewis - I think the confusion is about missing quotes around the `access_token` value.

Comment: @Stefan I don't understand. How could it work that way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error is that `|` symbol is not allowed in the proper URI, hence it needs to be escaped before it's parsed. URI comes with a method to do it for you:

```
uri = URI(URI.escape "https://graph.facebook.com/#{VANDALS_ID}/posts/?#{fb_access_token}")
uri.to_s     #=> https://graph.facebook.com/id-here/posts/?access_token=123456789%7Cabcdefghijk
```

When the url is requested, the server should automatically decode it, so all should work as expected.